# What label do you assign an object that is both occluded and truncated?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-recognition

Assume you have an image as shown below and you wish to label each object in the frame. How would you classify the blue prism, for example? It is truncated by the green sphere and occluded by the red prism. More generally, what is the tradeoff between occlusion and truncation in labeling images for machine learning/object recognition training data?

Note: I have been trying to follow the [Pascal VOC2011 annotation guidelines](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2011/guidelines.html).[image: Sample shapes together.]

Thank you in advance!